# matplotlib save .png files to .pptx and .html webpages format

Tags: html, python-2.7, matplotlib, powerpoint, figure

In matplotlib, I am capturing the pictures of figure in .png format using savefig() method. Say I have 4 pictures. Like how we convert .png files and create a pdf pages, I need to convert and save them into .pptx and .html webpages.

FYI Regarding pdf conversion we already have "**from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages**"

Please share your suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your own batch import routine, you can use VBA in PowerPoint.  This page on my PPT FAQ site will get you started:

BATCH IMPORT images into PowerPoint
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00050_BATCH_IMPORT_images_into_PowerPoint.htm

You can also use PowerPoint's Picture Album feature to do more or less the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I edited the post, I need this feature done in matplotlib python.